# Android: How to start an activity which is in device settings?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, settings

How can I start an activity which is in device settings? I need to start a settings page with intent.

Comment: I haven't code. I should use intent but I don't know right way.

Answer (score 0):

[These](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) are the activities the default `settings` app exposes to you so that you can create an intent with the appropriate [action](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Settings) set in it and launch the `Setting`'s activity that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you would like to start device settings from your app using intent.
Then please use:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

I know I am late. However this might help someone who want to do this task.